# Can you use word 'these' as a subject of a sentence that directly followed by a verb?

Tags: subjects

Today we came across a sentence that goes like this:

> Many physical objects constitute the IoT. **These send** data, share information and/or remotely control and manage a device or process.

My question here is is it correct to say 'these send'? Can you put a verb directly after 'these'? The sentence seems a little bit strange to me, but my friends think it's okay to say this. It sounds more right if it's:

> They send ....

BR,
ZZ

Comment: These are not the droids you're looking for.

Comment: Yes.  These can serve as a pronoun as well as an adjective.  In the sentence, "These send" is the plural form of "This is." No issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This, that, these, those** are demonstrative pronouns that can serve as the subject of verb, yes.

> These send data, share information, etc.

Whether it would be stylistically better  to use *they*, or to use **these** *adjectivally*, will depend on the particular case.

> These devices send data, share information and/or remotely control and manage a device or process.

Comment: My point is can you omit the devices here. So that it will be These send data, share information...

Comment: I understood your point and addressed it with my first sentence, though I did not provide an example. Now I have.

Answer (score 0):

> These send data . . .

This is entirely proper. Traditional grammar calls *this, these, that, those* employed as nominals "demonstrative pronouns". *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls such uses "fused-head NPs": a determiner (including quantifiers like *some* or *many*) or modifier 'fuses' with its head (the noun it determines or modifies) to act as a noun phrase.

> **These** <s>objects</s> send data.
>   **That** <s>proposition</s> is correct.
>   He likes apples, so I gave him **two** <s>apples</s>.
>   Most people are happy with this, but **some** <s>people</s> are upset.

Comment: Do CGEL regard this fusion as ellipsis of the head?

Comment: @TRomano No, though their argument is not entirely convincing: "[Adding the missing head] is not possible in cases like [*the most important of her criticisms* and *the rich*], however, and it is for this reason that we analyse the construction in terms of fusion of the head with a dependent function rather than in terms of ellipsis of the head." Note that I've made a small edit to my answer to accommodate these constructions.